# How to construct a dictionary which contain keys which are invalid keyword arguments, not using {}

Tags: python

If the use of `{}` is mere shortcut, to `dict()`, for creating a `dict`. So I was wondering how is one to create a `dict` which contains keys which are invalid keyword arguments, like `1`, `"1foo2bar3"` etc, without using the curly braces, or square brackets(with reference to the code below) and sticking to `dict()`?

Code below is not an option:

```
a = dict()
a[1] = 1
```

Comment: Those are all valid *keys* and `"foo2bar3"` is a valid *keyword argument*. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Also note that Cpython (at least) is overly permissive with what it allows as keyword arguments when passing them via dictionary unpacking.  e.g. the dict `foo = {'three stooges:['moe','larry','Curly']}` can be passed to a function which accepts `**kwargs` by `function(**foo)`

Comment: @mgilson +1 Interesting. Didn't know that.

Comment: @Aya -- It's an "optimization".  It checks to make sure all the keys are strings, because that's cheap.  It doesn't check to make sure that all the strings are valid identifiers because that would be expensive.

Comment: @hus787 Just out of curiosity, why exactly do you need to be able to do this?

Comment: @mgilson Even if it were syntactically valid to use an integer as a kwarg key (e.g. `f(1=2)`), the `1` would be passed as a string anyway, so you could replicate it with `def f(*args, **kwargs): print kwargs['1']` then call `f(**{'1': 2})`

Comment: @Aya -- I'm not sure I follow that comment ... the point is that `1` isn't a valid identifier, so it isn't syntatically valid ...

Comment: @Aya like I said, I was just wondering. Plus its nice to know.

Comment: @mgilson Well, when you call a function with a keyword arg, like `f(foo='bar')`, the `foo` is not evaluated, it's just converted to a string. This would mean the OP's assertion that `"1foo2bar3"` is an invalid kwarg isn't true, since you could pass it as `f(**{"1foo2bar3": some_value})`.

Comment: @Aya -- But techinally, `"1foo2bar3"` isn't a valid kwarg because it is an invalid identifier and kwargs passed via a mapping are supposed to be valid identifiers.  Just because it works (on Cpython), doesn't mean it's technically legal.  You have the same problem with the expression `2 is 1+1`.  on Cpython, that'll be True, but it certainly isn't guaranteed behavior.

Comment: @mgilson Perhaps. I can't find anything in the Python docs to support the argument (i.e. if "1foo2bar3" is a valid kwarg) either way. All I can find is from the docs for [`apply()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply): "If the optional *keywords* argument is present, it must be a dictionary whose keys are strings."

Comment: @Aya -- I actually asked about this very issue a few weeks back on [the python mailing list](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/1061605?do=post_view_threaded)

Comment: @mgilson Looks like this was partly addressed in [issue #8419](http://bugs.python.org/issue8419), but only for the case where the keys were integers. A quick test shows that CPython, Jython, and pypy are all happy with `dict(**{'1':1})`. There was a [very long thread about this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-April/099427.html), and Guido seemed to think it was okay as long as the keys were strings.

Comment: @mgilson Actually, a fairer test would be `(lambda *args, **kwargs: kwargs)(**{'1':1})` (which also works on jython and pypy), since CPython 2.x still allows `dict(**{1:1})`, although it doesn't work in 3.x, so that's arguably a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean using the default dict constructor to create a dictionary?

```
>>> a = dict((x, x) for x in range(10))
>>> a
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}
```

It takes a collection of tuples, and turns it into a dictionary, usually combined with generator expressions like above - but you could also give it a previously prepared collection of tuples.

```
>>> dict([(1, 1), ('a', 'a')])
{'a': 'a', 1: 1}
```

Using your examples:

```
>>> dict([(1, None), ("1foo", None), ("foo2bar3", None)])
{1: None, '1foo': None, 'foo2bar3': None}
```

Comment: `zip` is also a common way of getting an iterable of `(key,value)` tuples: `dict(zip(keys, values))`

Answer (score 0):

`{}` is not a "mere" shortcut for `dict()`. It's a shortcut in terms of performance in addition to the length difference.

http://doughellmann.com/2012/11/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2.html

You're better off using dictionary literals unless you need to support a really old version of Python that doesn't include them, or if you're doing some sort of list or other comprehension to build the dict with a version of Python < 2.7 (as versions of Python less than 2.7 don't support dict comprehensions [i.e. `{x: y for x, y in some_iterable}`], I believe).